# How to set page number on outer bottom side of the page in classicthesis?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, koma-script, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` along with a Koma-script class.

I was able to put the page number on the outer bottom side of the page. But, a page number is still present in the heading and also it is outer than the one I put in the bottom.

How can I remove it from the header and make the one in the bottom to be outer like it was in the heading?

Thanks!

### Edit

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright, titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
            footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
            BCOR=25mm,fontsize=11pt,a4paper,%
            american,%
            ]{scrreprt}


\input{classicthesis-config}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{a chapter}
\lipsum

\chapter{second chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

'classicthesis-config' can be found within the `classicthesis` package. With this I obtain the page number at the header and at the outer bottom. I just want it only at the outer bottom and indented as it was in the header.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look at the `fancyhdr` package (and serach for it on this site; there will be plenty posts on this topic that you can find). It suits exactly your problems.

Comment: I saw now that you tagged your question koma-script. Does that mean that you use one of the koma classes?

Comment: ... and maybe add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Ruben `classicthesis` uses the obsolete package `scrpage2` to deal with headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classicthesis` is using the obsolete package `scrpage2` to set headers and footers. I adapted the original code and want to say, that this isn't really *best-practice*.

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,
    titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
    footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
            % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
    BCOR=25mm,fontsize=11pt,a4paper,%
    american,%
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\clearscrheadfoot
    \lehead{\headmark}
    \rohead{\headmark}
    \lefoot[\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}]{\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}}
    \rofoot[\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}]{\rlap{\small\kern2em\pagemark}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Crazy Capybara}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```